# \mathsfup and \symsfup for variables

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, sans-serif

Unicode-math documentation v. 0.8o says in §3.1:

> A boldface variable name should be printed using the math font, whereas a boldface operator name should be printed using the text font.

Now, how about typesetting multi-letter variables and multi-letter sorts (in other terminology, types) in multi-sorted logics?  Which font should they be set up with, say, in the following example:

"For a variable identifier var : Int and a function identifier fun : Int → Bool the term fun(var) has sort Bool."

?

Let us continue:

> The five new symbol font commands that behave in this way are: `\symup`, `\symit`, `\symbf`,`\symsf` , and `\symit`.  These commands switch to single-letter mathematical symbols (generally within the same OpenType font). The legacy `\math..` commands switch to text fonts that are set up to be- have correctly in mathematics, and should be used for multi-letter identifiers.

Ok, but what is, say, `\mathsfup` supposed to do?  Notice that `\mathsfup` ∉ {`\symup`, `\symit`, `\symbf`,`\symsf` , and `\symit`} and `\mathsfup` is not a legacy command. Table 1 says `\mathsfup` is the same as `\symsfup` but what I am missing is the font used for `\symsfup` or `\mathsfup`.

Further, I cannot even find a proper definition of `\symsfup`:

```
$ grep -air "symsfup" /usr/share/*tex*
$
```

Where is it?

Comment: Is `\symfsup` in the title of your query a typo?

Comment: For the record: I did *not* suggest the spelling `\symfsup`. To the contrary, I had asked you if there was a typo in the title of your posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no explicit definition of `\symsfup` or other similar commands: they are implicitly defined as part of the set up.

Consider the following test file:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

$\symsf{A}$ $\mathsf{A}$

$\symsfup{A}$ $\mathsfup{A}$

$\symbfsf{A}$ $\mathbfsf{A}$

$\symbfsfup{A}$ $\mathbfsfup{A}$

\showoutput
\end{document}
```

Isolating the relevant parts from the log file, we can see

```latex
....\mathon
....\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 glyph#3126
....\mathoff
....\mathon
....\TU/lmss/m/n/10 glyph#27
....\mathoff

....\mathon
....\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 glyph#3126
....\mathoff
....\mathon
....\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 glyph#3126
....\mathoff

....\mathon
....\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 glyph#3250
....\mathoff
....\mathon
....\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 glyph#3250
....\mathoff

....\mathon
....\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 glyph#3250
....\mathoff
....\mathon
....\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 glyph#3250
....\mathoff
```

As you see, there is a difference only between `\symsf` and `\mathsf`, as written in the documentation.

In case you need to differentiate between `\symbfsf` and `\mathbfsf`, you can define the latter with

```
\setmathfontface⟨\mathbfsf⟩{<your text sans font>}[⟨the required features⟩]
```

so that multiletter strings in `\mathbfsf` are treated as if they were text, rather than juxtaposed symbols.

Comment: @Just_A_Man Multiletter variables should use the text sans font (which will usually match the math sans font, of course).

Comment: @Just_A_Man Yes. Look at what you get from `\symit{diff}` and `\mathit{diff}`.