# Exclamation and question marks in mathematical bold sans-serif upright Times or Times-like font

Tags: math-fonts, newtxmath, times, tex-gyre-math, timesfont

Continuing [\mathsfup and \symsfup for variables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537283), we try to get bold sans-serif upright exclamation and question marks from NewTX and TeX Gyre Termes Math.  However, an attempt to typeset them makes me feel as if the fonts would offer only one possible exclamation mark and only one possible question mark.  Namely, feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifTUTeX
  \tracinglostchars=2
  \usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
  \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
  \setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=0.88]%%% Sclaing smewhat ok.
  \setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}%%% No explicit turning on ligatures for the monospaced font.
  \setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[helvratio=.9]{newtxtext}%%% Sclaing smewhat ok.
  \usepackage[slantedGreek,subscriptcorrection]{newtxmath}
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbfsf}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{bx}{n}
\fi
\begin{document}\noindent
\(?\mathbf{?}\mathsf{?}\mathbfsf{?}\ifTUTeX\mathbfsfup{?}\mathbfsfit{?}\fi\)\\
\(!\mathbf{!}\mathsf{!}\mathbfsf{!}\ifTUTeX\mathbfsfup{!}\mathbfsfit{!}\fi\)\\
\ifTUTeX
\(?\symbf{?}\symsf{?}\symbfsf{?}\symbfsfup{?}\symbfsfit{?}\)\\
\(!\symbf{!}\symsf{!}\symbfsf{!}\symbfsfup{!}\symbfsfit{!}\)
\fi
\end{document}
```

to `pdflatex` yields

[image: output of pdflatex]

As you see, ALL question marks are visually equal, and ALL exclamation marks are visually equal.

The same code, fed to `lualatex`, yields

[image: output of lualatex]

Again, ALL question marks come out visually equal, and ALL exclamation marks come out visually equal.

If we substitute exclamation and question marks by Latin letters, we see that their shapes get properly changed.

In the case of question and exclamation marks, we get no feedback about failures to produce any nondefault symbol shape:

```
$ egrep -i "(warn)|(error)|(fail)|(miss)|(undef)" mwe.log
$
```

1. Any idea how to get the mathematical bold sans-serif upright question mark (?) using

1.1 `pdflatex` and NewTX

1.2 `lualatex` and TeX Gyre Termes Math?

2. Any idea how to get the mathematical bold sans-serif upright exclamation mark (!) using

2.1 `pdflatex` and NewTX

2.2 `lualatex` and TeX Gyre Termes Math?

If NewTX and TeX Gyre Termes Math wouldn't do, which pair of Times-like fonts (perhaps, even including a variant of Times itself) to take and how?  Or should we resort to some packages or nontrivial commands (`\usepackage{bm}`, `\bm`, `\boldmath`, `\boldsymbol`, …)  What would be the cleanest way?

Comment: the unicode math ranges (the main target of `\symxx` ) do not include punctuation symbols

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh. Alright. So what do we do for `lualatex` then? Use `\textbf{\textsf{?}}` or `\textsf{\textbf{?}}` or similar?

Comment: for a one-off use you could do that or set up a bold sans math font `\mathbfsf`or whatever for more structured font setup

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's not a one-off, I'm afraid. In our computer-science text, we typeset normal-font question/exclamation marks for actions such as `c?` or `c!` over arrows when describing the operational semantics of the modeling language CSP by Hoare. We wish to typeset bold sans-serif question/exclamation marks when we write commands of a programming language, such as ***c* ! 1** or ***c* ? *v***, which operate on the channels between processes. Currently, we typeset about 55 question marks of both kinds altogether and 76 exclamation marks of both kinds altogether.

Comment: declaremathalphabet should work, let me trace your mwe...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've just uploaded the log of https://pastebin.com/raw/8j1aHFre to https://pastebin.com/raw/seEQKFUp , to expire 1 y from now. It was produced with `pdflatex` from a stock Debian installation. With `pdflatex` from the current TeX Live, the output is no better.

Answer (score 1):

adding `\showoutput` to your example produces, with pdflatex

```
....\mathon
....\OT1/minntx/m/n/10 ?
....\hbox(6.74998+0.09)x4.44
.....\OT1/minntx/m/n/10 ?
....\hbox(6.74998+0.09)x4.44
.....\OT1/minntx/m/n/10 ?
....\hbox(6.74998+0.09)x4.44
.....\OT1/minntx/m/n/10 ?
....\mathoff
```

So the ? are "visually equal" because they are the same glyph.

Adding

```
\mathchardef\qqq\mathcode`? \show\qqq
```

produces

```
> \qqq=\mathchar"503F.
```

So ? always comes from the operators `\fam0` with `\mathclose` (5) spacing  it does not change with math alphabet commands.

Adding

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\qn}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`?}
\show\qn
```

produces

```
> \qn=\mathchar"703F.
```

which is a ? with `\mathord` spacing (0) and variable (7) `\fam`

[image]

Or in the log

```
....\OT1/minntx/m/n/10 ?
....\OT1/minntx/b/n/10 ?
....\T1/qhv/m/n/10 ?
....\T1/qhv/b/n/10 ?
```

From

```
\(\qn\mathbf{\qn}\mathsf{\qn}\mathbfsf{\qn}\)
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\showoutput
\ifTUTeX
  \tracinglostchars=2
  \usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
  \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
  \setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=0.88]%%% Sclaing smewhat ok.
  \setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}%%% No explicit turning on ligatures for the monospaced font.
  \setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[helvratio=.9]{newtxtext}%%% Sclaing smewhat ok.

  \usepackage[slantedGreek,subscriptcorrection]{newtxmath}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\qn}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`?}
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbfsf}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{bx}{n}
\fi
\begin{document}



\noindent
\(?\mathbf{?}\mathsf{?}\mathbfsf{?}\ifTUTeX\mathbfsfup{?}\mathbfsfit{?}\fi\)\\
\(!\mathbf{!}\mathsf{!}\mathbfsf{!}\ifTUTeX\mathbfsfup{!}\mathbfsfit{!}\fi\)\\
\(\qn\mathbf{\qn}\mathsf{\qn}\mathbfsf{\qn}\)
\ifTUTeX
\(?\symbf{?}\symsf{?}\symbfsf{?}\symbfsfup{?}\symbfsfit{?}\)\\
\(!\symbf{!}\symsf{!}\symbfsf{!}\symbfsfup{!}\symbfsfit{!}\)
\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx!!! I've just checked, and this goes well for `pdflatex`.  What do we do for `lualatex`? The same definition of `\qn` seems to produce a normal question mark …

Comment: @AlbertNash I was planning to leave that as an "exercise for the reader":-) essentially the same code will work but you will have to supply the fonts and (see unicode-math) make sure \mathsf really selects a sans font, and is not made an alias for \symbf (which uses the unicode sans range which has no "?")  unicode-math can do either. No time now but if you don't get it working ping me later and I may look

Comment: Since you made “?” an operator: the intended usages are “channel?”, “channel?var”, “channel!”, and “channel!expression”. The question mark (as well as the exclamation mark) is a postfix command (i.e., the argument of the command comes before the keyword, similar to a factorial, e.g. “3!”) or an infix command (i.e., the argument of the command comes around the keyword, similar to the addition, e.g., “2+3”). Does the “operators“ class really suit or is there a better class?

Comment: @AlbertNash  I made `?` a letter (`\mathalpha`)  like `x`  so it gets no spacing, and picks up the current font. the `{operators}` argument there is refering to the font used for operators such as `\log` and `\sin`, so `\mathrm`, typically. So bascally this makes `?` act like a digit `0` :  by default in the upright font but using whatever is current with `\mathsf{..}` etc